# How to show different views depending on the fe_usergroup in Typo3 6.2 Extbase extension efficiently?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, usergroups

Right now I'm getting the currently logged-in user's usergroup(s) in my action-controller like this:

```
$roles = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->groupData['title'];
```

I pass this information to my view and then do stuff like this:

```
<f:if condition="{0:role} == {0:'management'}">
...
```

I'm not sure if this is a good way...I think not - so I thought of this:
For example in: `listAction()`:
Depending on the usergroup different properties should be shown.
I thought about working with sections there by naming them after a usergroup and doing something like this:

```
<f:for each="{appointments}" as="appointment">
 <f:render section="{0:role} arguments="{appointment:appointment}"/>
...
```

But I wonder if there's a better way...?
And how I could test my views the best way - my idea:
If a have a test-user who belongs to all usergroups it would be nice to be able to switch my views while in the frontend to see if all the views work without having to log in with a different test user for a different usergroup everytime.
The way I'm doing it it's not possible.

So my questions:

1. Is my approach best practice or how could I make this even simpler and automated?
2. Is there an easy way to test the views like I described with a test-user who belongs to all usergroups?

I searched around in the [Typo3 Basics](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/2-BasicPrinciples/Index.html) but couldn't find a solution or best practice to my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to connect rights to see certain fields to groups. As people can be in more than one group the fields that a person can see can vary a lot. If you make sections / partials for each group you have to repeat a lot of fields in the templates.
A more flexible way would be to first collect the fields that a user can see based on the various groups they are a member of. You could set in the `settings` of your extension which fields are visible for each group. In the controller you can combine the fields for all the groups of the user and finally pass the array of fields to the view. The view can simply iterate over the list and render each visible field.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea - but what/where are those `settings`?  
And what exactly do you mean by "fields"? Strings of names of the properties, or should I make a section for each field and then it would be the names of those sections?

Comment: Every extbase extension has a "settings" section in the TypoScript configuration: `plugin.tx_myextensionname.settings`. Below that key you can put any configuration you want. In your controller you can access it with `$this->settings` and in Fluid with `{settings}`.
By "fields" I meant the properties you want to show.
With 2-3 user groups it wouldn't be a problem to have a separate section for each group, but you also have to take into account combinations of groups. Then it's easier to first see which properties must be shown.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the settings section yet - but if the view just iterates over the fields from `settings` how do I differentiate between things like `<f:form.radio...`, `<f:form.select`, `<f:form.textarea` and so on? (That's why I thought of the section names)

Comment: Only you know which property needs what kind of field to function, so you could make sections or partials for each kind of form field and use a switch viewhelper to render each possible field. You can pass all necessary information to a partial / section to render a field for a certain property. You can then iterate over the list of accessible fields and render each field as the right type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly with the switch viewhelper (which variable to examine) and I don't know how the iteration can render each field correctly (I only could think of iteration over section/partial names) - 
could you provide some example code (in your answer maybe)? Because I think then I would immediately get your meaning.

Comment: I now got the `settings` object working, and it helps a lot! My initial problem was that I wrote it in `constants.txt`, it didn't work there, but it worked in `setup.txt` :)